# vsto C# for excel (form covered excel warning message)

Tags: c#, vsto

I have a question and i am not able to figure it out

```
form.Show();
form.TopMost = true;
```

I want to display a form to user but when user try to close the workbook, excel warning message come up, like "this workbook is not save, do you want to save it?" but that message is displayed under my form so user cannot see it and also my form is inaccesible at that moment( you cannot close it),so user cannot interact with Excel warning message(to save or not to save)

Basically, I want create something with same behavior like "Excel Find form" (Ctrl+F). Its topmost is true, but when user close workbook, find form is hidden and Excel warning come up(save or not save), after Excel warning is closed, Find form is show again.

Thank you.

Comment: Try with form.showdialog and call on workbook closed event

Comment: I don't want to use modal dialog, i want users to be able to interact with the spreadsheet. same behavior like Excel Find form (Ctrl+F)